# Change date format (keep "variables")

Tags: php, datetime

I'm trying to change my dateformat according to the country the user is using.

Currently I've come up with this:

```
function format_date($date = '', $format=null)
    {
        if($date == "0000-00-00") return "";
        $DateTime = new DateTime($date);
                if(!$format){
                    $CI =& get_instance();
                    switch($CI->session->userdata("country")){
                        case 3:
                            $format = "d-m-Y H:i:s";
                        break;
                        default:
                            $format = "Y-m-d H:i:s";
                        break;
                    }
                }
                return $DateTime->format($format);
    }
```

But if the format of $date is:

**2013-03-15 15:50:30**

I want the output to be:

**15-03-2013 15:50:30**

and if the format is:

**2013-03-15**

I want the output to be:

**15-03-2013**

instead of:

**15-03-2013 00:00:00**

if you wanter what the argument format is for is that I should be about to force it to a format.

EDIT:

Sometimes we only need 2013-04-12 16:52.

And it should be able to format here too:/

Answer (score 0):

use [mkdate](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) for this

```
/* 2013-04-18 */
echo date("Y-m-d", mktime(0, 0, 0, 12, 30, 1997));

/* 18-04-2013 */
echo date("d-m-Y", mktime(0, 0, 0, 12, 30, 1997));
```

more example you find on the [php.net page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
function format_date($date = '', $format=null)
{
    if($date == "0000-00-00") return "";

    // Compare len of str $date
    if(strlen($date) > 10)
        $his = " H:i:s";
    else
        $his = "";
    $DateTime = new DateTime($date);
            if(!$format){
                $CI =& get_instance();
                switch($CI->session->userdata("country")){
                    case 3:
                        $format = "d-m-Y" . $his;
                    break;
                    default:
                        $format = "Y-m-d" . $his;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return $DateTime->format($format);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `strpos` to check whether the string includes a space (then it obviously has a timestamp).

I've created a function for you that takes a `$date` argument being eg. `2012-01-01 01:00:00` or `2012-02-03`, `$dateFormat` being the [`date()`](http://www.php.net/date) format if no time has been specified, and `$dateTimeFormat` being the [`date()`](http://www.php.net/date) format if the time **has** been specified.

```
<?php
    function DateFormatDynamic($date, $dateFormat, $dateTimeFormat) {
        $unixTime = strtotime($date);
        if (strpos($date, " ") !== false) {
            return date($dateTimeFormat, $unixTime);
        } else {
            return date($dateFormat, $unixTime);
        }
    }

    var_dump(DateFormatDynamic("2013-03-15", "d-m-Y", "d-m-Y H:i:s"));
    //string(10) "15-03-2013"

    var_dump(DateFormatDynamic("2013-03-15 15:23:00", "d-m-Y", "d-m-Y H:i:s"));
    //string(19) "15-03-2013 15:23:00"

    var_dump(DateFormatDynamic("2013-03-15 15:23", "d-m-Y", "d-m-Y H:i"));
    //string(19) "15-03-2013 15:23"
?>
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/8k13GhAU)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try **after verifying the date format**

```
$d = '2013-03-15 15:50:30';
$d2 = '2013-03-15';

function myFormatDate($d){
    $format = 'd-m-Y';
    if(count(explode(' ',$d)) > 1)
        $format = 'd-m-Y H:i:s';
    return date($format, strtotime($d));
}

var_dump(myFormatDate($d));
var_dump(myFormatDate($d2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a hacky solution but you could use:

```
$date = $DateTime->format($format);

if (strpos($date, '00:00:00')) {

    $date = substr($date, 0, strpos($date, '00:00:00') - 1);
}

return $date;
```

The jist of is if the date contains 00:00:00, then remove that part of the string and the `- 1` accounts for the space which is between the date and the time.